# "GET /store/hello/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0 with Class-Based-Views (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I use **Class-Based-Views** with **"post" method** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

class Hello(View):
    # Here
    def post(self, request):
        return render(request, 'store/index.html')
```

Then, this is **"urls.py"** below:

```py
# "store/urls.py"

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "store"

urlpatterns = [
    path("hello/", views.Hello.as_view(), name="hello"),
]
```

Then, I got this error below:

> Method Not Allowed (GET): /store/hello/
> Method Not Allowed (GET): /store/hello/
> Method Not Allowed: /store/hello/
> Method Not Allowed: /store/hello/
> [03/Aug/2022 22:18:45] "GET /store/hello/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

So, are there any ways to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **"get" method** as shown below instead of **"post" method**:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

class Hello(View):
    # Here
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'store/index.html')

    # def post(self, request):
    #     return render(request, 'store/index.html')
```